# Window server is automatically changing file extension from filename.txt to filename.txt.OLD

Tags: windows

An SQL server job is creating a txt file in the windows directory, but after some time, the file extension is changing from filename.txt to filename.txt.OLD. I am not able to find the solution. Please help me

Comment: I'm fairly certain there is no programming on your side involved.

Comment: There is no programming there to rename the file, I am suspecting it windows setting somewhere.....

Comment: Then why are you asking on StackOverflow? This is a Q&A site for programming questions.